# Writing a generic FluentValidation custom validator to check unique constraint

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, generics, fluentvalidation

Really new to C#, ASP.NET MVC and FluentValidation.

i have a user model like:

```
public class UserDetails{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

for now, i've been validating the UserName and Email using FluentValidation, something like:

```
 public AdminDetailsValidator(){
        RuleFor(ad => ad.UserName).NotNull().Must(UniqueUserName(UserName)).WithMessage("UserName not Available");
        RuleFor(ad => ad.Email).NotNull().Must(UniqueEmail(Email)).WithMessage("This Email id has already been registered"); ;
    }

    public bool UniqueUserName(string un)
    {
        if (UserDbContext.userDetails.SingleOrDefault(p => p.UserName == un) == null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public bool UniqueEmail(string em)
    {
        if (UserDbContext.userDetails.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Email == em) == null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

But i'd rather want a more generic UniqueValidator, that i can use with multiple classes and properties. Or Atleast, i don't have to make a separate function for each property. So i looked into the custom validators. But i have no idea, how i can use that feature for my needs. 
I want to do something like this:

```
RuleFor(ad => ad.Email).NotNull().SetValidator(new UniquePropertyValidator<UserDbContext>(userDetails.Email).WithMessage("This Email id has already been registered");
```

Is that even possible to do that? I want to pass the DbContext as type parameter and property as an argument(or some variation of it, whichever works). and the method can check the property against the table and return if it's unique or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked into using lambdas and generics? I haven't used FluentValidation so this might not be the correct method for a validator.

```
var dbContext = new UserDbContext();
RuleFor(ud => ud.Email)
    .NotNull()
    .SetValidator(
        new UniquePropertyValidator<UserDetails>
         (ud, ud => ud.Email, () => dbcontext.userDetails)
    .WithMessage("This Email id has already been registered");

public class UniquePropertyValidator<T> {
    public UniquePropertyValidator(T entity, Func<T,string> propertyAccessorFunc, Func<IEnumerable<T>> collectionAccessorFunc) {
        _entity = entity;
        _propertyAccessorFunc =  propertyAccessorFunc;
        _collectionAccessorFunc =collectionAccessorFunc;
    }

    public bool Validate(){
       //Get all the entities by executing the lambda
       var entities = _collectionAccessorFunc();

       //Get the value of the entity that we are validating by executing the lambda
       var propertyValue = _propertyAccessorFunc(_entity);

       //Find the matching entity by executing the propertyAccessorFunc against the 
       //entities in the collection and comparing that with the result of the entity 
       //that is being validated. Warning SingleOrDefault will throw an exception if
       //multiple items match the supplied predicate
       //http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb342451%28v=vs.100%29.aspx
       var matchingEntity = entities.SingleOrDefault(e => _propertyAccessorFunc(e) == propertyValue);
       return matchingEntity == null;
    }
}
```

Comment: You may want not to pre-create the db context.

Comment: Yeah good point, normally I'd probably have the validator constructed using dependency injection but I didn't want to make the question more complicated then it already is

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply(same can't be said about myself..been busy with another project). i can understand most of what you suggested, except the parameters inside `UniquePropertyValidator<UserDetails>(....)`. i am giving it a look right away. Also, won't `ud=>ud.Email` will be property value? how can i accept it as a function(`Func<string> propertyAccessorFucn`)?

Comment: @MridulKashyap There was a typo in the signature of the constructor. It was supposed to be func that would accept a T and return a string. Fixed in edit

Comment: understood. i'm not sure how to do the lambda expression part. but i'd like to look for it myself, before asking. i'll keep you people updated as to where i reach with this.

Thanks for all the help. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have also been trying to find an elegant solution for this validator, but the solution provided so far seems to fetch all the data and then check for uniqueness. That is not very good in my opinion.

When trying to use the implementation proposed below, I get an error that LINQ to Entities does not support Invoke (i.e. executing a `Func<>` inside the `Where` clause). Is there any workaround?

```
public class UniqueFieldValidator<TObject, TViewModel, TProperty> : PropertyValidator where TObject : Entity where TViewModel : Entity
{
    private readonly IDataService<TObject> _dataService;
    private readonly Func<TObject, TProperty> _property;

    public UniqueFieldValidator(IDataService<TObject> dataService, Func<TObject, TProperty> property)
        : base("La propiedad {PropertyName} tiene que ser unica.")
    {
        _dataService = dataService;
        _property = property;
    }

    protected override bool IsValid(PropertyValidatorContext context)
    {
        var model = context.Instance as TViewModel;
        var value = (TProperty)context.PropertyValue;

        if (model != null && _dataService.Where(t => t.Id != model.Id && Equals(_property(t), value)).Any())
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}

public class ArticuloViewModelValidator : AbstractValidator<ArticuloViewModel>
{
    public ArticuloViewModelValidator(IDataService<Articulo> articuloDataService)
    {
        RuleFor(a => a.Codigo).SetValidator(new UniqueFieldValidator<Articulo, ArticuloViewModel, int>(articuloDataService, a => a.Codigo));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can solve this problem simply by working with LINQ to Entities.
Here is a static method used to determine whether the given value is unique in the specified `DbSet`:

```
static class ValidationHelpers
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Determines whether the specified <paramref name="newValue"/> is unique inside of
    /// the given <paramref name="dbSet"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dbSet"></param>
    /// <param name="getColumnSelector">
    /// Determines the column, with which we will compare <paramref name="newValue"/>
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="newValue">
    /// Value, that will be checked for uniqueness
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="cancellationToken"></param>
    /// <typeparam name="TEntity"></typeparam>
    /// <typeparam name="TColumn"></typeparam>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static async Task<bool> IsColumnUniqueInsideOfDbSetAsync<TEntity, TColumn>(DbSet<TEntity> dbSet,
        Expression<Func<TEntity, TColumn>> getColumnSelector,
        TColumn newValue,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        where TEntity : class
    {
        return !await dbSet
            .Select(getColumnSelector)
            .AnyAsync(column => column.Equals(newValue), cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

#### Example of using

We have the following entity:

```
public class Category
{
    // ...
    public string Title { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

And a `DbContext` class:

```
public interface ApplicationDbContext
{
    // ...
    public DbSet<Category> Category { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

Let's say a user wants to create a new category. We want to validate the title of this category for uniqueness:

```
RuleFor(c => c.Title)
    .MustAsync
    (
        (newTitle, token) => ValidationHelpers.IsColumnUniqueInsideOfDbSetAsync
            (_context.Category, c => c.Title, newTitle, token)
    )
    .WithMessage("{PropertyName} must be unique");
```

*Note*: `_context` is an object of type `ApplicationDbContext`.